# Tricky logic to calculate unique recent visitors in a Django app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a live web-based chat app made in Django. Users can form groups where other users can congregate, leave messages (called `replies`) and photos. The url every user visits to access a group is:

```
url(r'^group/(?P<pk>\d+)/reply/$', auth(GroupView.as_view()), name="group_reply"),
```

where `pk` is `group.pk`.

My question is: **how can I get a list (or set) of all distinct users who accessed a certain group's URL in the last 5 mins?** Essentially, I'm trying to calculate the number of *unique recent visitors* for each group. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this, though I guess sessions information could help? (I'm using [django user_sessions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-sessions) in this project, which

> "makes session objects a first class citizen like other ORM objects"

).

---

In case required, the model behind a group is:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    topic = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(200)], null=True)
    rules = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)], null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    private = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    category = models.CharField(choices=TYPE, default=1, max_length=25)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And the model behind posting a *reply* in each group is:

```
class Reply(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_pic_to_location, null=True, blank=True )
```

And `User` is a vanilla `django.contrib.auth` `user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything that is collecting the data you need. If you want to record visits to a page, you will need to build a model to do that; a simple one with FKs to User (for the visitor) and Group (for the group being visited), plus a timestamp, should be enough. Then your GroupView can make an entry in that table every time a user visits.

Comment: To clarify, I want to measure *unique visits*, so I should use `distinct('user')` on the queryset of the model you mention in your answer?